# How to start right activity after filtering listView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

My app has search feature in ActionBar that can filter listView in MainActivity. Unfortunately, after I filter listView and click on first element on the list, app opens activity of the first element on the list before filtering, instead of doing nothing (because I haven't created other activities yet). I would like to have maintain position from original listView. My code is specific:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewElements);
    ArrayList<String> arrayElements = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayElements.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_elements)));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayElements);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (id == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, wodor.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: You need to use two arraylists. One with full data and one for the filter. Set filter arraylist in adapter.

Comment: Can you kindly provide me with a sample code?